# Best Practices to implement a menu system in a QML game?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm relatively new to QML/QtQuick 2 and I quite enjoy it. To start mastering it I am implementing a small fullscreen game. My idea is to have the (simple) game and when the uses presses up the ESC key to pop-up a graphical menu with some settings.

Now I have all the basics running but I'm not completely sure which is the best Declarative way of managing the menu and passing keyboard focus back and forth.
Is it better to statically create the menu and make it hidden in my main file, like this:

```
MyMenuSystem {
   visible: false
}
```

and then set it to "visible" when I need it? Or defer loading it and use Loader and create a new instance? I prefer to have it declared in my QML code for cleanness, but what is the best practice here? Or is there some component to switch between views that I'm completely missing? I could find very little information and examples on this topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kinda broad and could lead to opinionated answers, but since it's a topic close to my heart, I thought I'd try to give some advice.

#### Loader

I tend to only use Loader when the item I need to load is only relevant under certain circumstances. For example, if a document is open that doesn't support a certain feature, then the UI element that represents that feature can be put into a Loader. A benefit of this (besides a (usually) very small increase in performance) is that it avoids the need to add lots of null checks for that feature. For example, if you don't use a Loader in this case, you might end up with a lot of code that looks like this:

```
text: optionalFeature.foo ? optionalFeature.foo.bar : ""
```

With a Loader, you control when the item is loaded, such that it's only loaded when the optional feature is enabled. Then the code becomes much nicer:

```
text: optionalFeature.foo.bar
```

#### Popup

For an in-game menu, I'd use a [`Popup`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html). This is good if you want the user to be able to see the game in the background, though you can also obscure that with an [overlay](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-overlay.html#overlay-attached-prop), if you wanted.

#### StackView

If you don't want to use a popup, then I'd suggest [`StackView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html). You should probably be using this for each screen in your game anyway, as it is a perfect fit for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I managed to do a Menu System:
I used Component to create a Component and createObject() to turn it into an instance of that component.

MyMenu.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Popup {
    /* Menu Item 1 */
    /* etc etc */

}
```

---

Game.qml:

```
Component {
   id: myMenuId
   MyMenu {

   }
}

Game {
  id: myGameId
property var dynamicItem
 Keys.onPressed: {
          if (event.key == Qt.Key_ESC) {
              dynamicItem = myMenuId.createObject(myGameId);
              dynamicItem.open()
           }

      }

}
```